# MVC 4 approach with HttpGet and HttpPost

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using  `MVC 4` with a Razor View. The View has two `Dropdown` Lists and a `Submit` button.

```
<form  id="mutualTradeFormId" method="get" action="@Url.Action("Index")">
     <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select id="FundFamilyId" name="FundFamily" class="FundFamilyClass">
            @foreach (var item in Model.MutualFundFamilies)
            {
                <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text </option>  
            }
        </select>
    </div>
    <select id="FundId" name="Fund" class="FundClass">
        @foreach (var item in Model.mutualFunds)
        {
            <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>  
        }
    </select>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="button" id="btnPreview" value="Preview Order" />
    </div>
</form>
```

To load the second `DropdownList`, I use an `AJAX` call and this is why the `<form>` tag uses `Get` instead of `Post`

```
$(document).on("change", '#FundFamilyId', function (e) {
    SubmitFormjs();
});
function SubmitFormjs() {
    var form = $('#mutualTradeFormId');
    $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $('#fundListId').replaceWith(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
};
```

CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult Index( string FundFamily = "")
{
    if (FundFamily.Length > 0)
    {
        _vmfund.lstMutualFunds = DalOrders.GetFundsByFamilyId(FundFamily);
    }
    ....
    return View(_vmfund);
}
```

The form tag has a `method="get"` in order to allow the populating of the second `DropdownList`. For the button click, I would like to do a Post and I don't know how to structure the controller to do `HttpGet` for the DDL population and an `HttpPost` for the button click

Comment: Just use `method="get"` in the `<form>` tag, and in the ajax call, use `type: 'get',`

Comment: Why not populate the dropdown before the page is rendered, and pass it down?

Comment: I agree with JPG, you typically want to pre-load that data in a view-model and then pass it to the view, then just load your dropdown that way.

Comment: I also strongly recommend you go to the MVC site and learn the basics of how to create a view using the `HtmlHelper` methods (you current implementation means no 2-way model binding, no client side validation, no ability to edit existing data). And for correctly implementing cascading dropdownlists, refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym))

Comment: Thank you for for the suggestions.  To be clear, there are two dropdown lists, id="FundFamilyId" and  id="FundId, On the page load, FundFamilyId is prepopulated by the Controller, however the second is populated when an item from the first from chosen.  The solution was to make a WEB API call to retrieve the data for the second DDL, so I would not have to Post back to the Server.  The form needs method=Post for the button click event